# text with multiple span

Tags: html, css

I would like align my text like this example http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/. My problem is that my text is not centered and the second line has an espace ...

My HTML

```
    <div class="row"> 
<div class="span12"> 


    Hello <span data-bind="text: viewModel.firstName()"></span>,
    We have analyzed <span data-bind="text: viewModel.user.nbAnalyzedMails()"></span>
    emails, extracted <span data-bind="text: viewModel.user.newMessages()"></span>
    new messages, please check report in your dashboard ></span> <br>



</div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {text-align: center}
```

Comment: In your fiddle the text sure looks centered to me.

Comment: you want each span to be in a different line?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If I paste your example here in the HTML page of the fiddle you provided, the result is centered. It does however, have only one line.

Comment: yea I just edited my code but it was not the solution of my issue

Comment: Your span data probably creates extra space. Could you put your binding into hidden fields, then using JS getting the values and remove spaces if needed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/49Krx/9/ This what you looking for?

Comment: I am confused on what you are trying to do exactly. More information would be appreciated.

Comment: New jsFiddle, I would like that contacts and Hello aligned vertically, no blank space 

http://jsfiddle.net/49Krx/10/

Comment: So you want the text center aligned but left aligned?

Comment: yesss block entirely left aligned

Comment: why not try justify: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/49Krx/11/

Comment: I'm confused. If the problem is that you don't want the text to be centered, why do you center it to begin with?

Comment: Don't use .row {text-align: center} css... you are using bootstrap, the text-align center class is ="text-center"

Answer (score 1):

check this

CSS

```
.row {text-align: center}
.row .span12 p{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="span12"> 
        <p>Hello <span data-bind="text: viewModel.firstName()"></span>,</p>
        <p>We have analyzed <span data-bind="text: viewModel.user.nbAnalyzedMails()"></span></p>
        <p>emails, extracted <span data-bind="text: viewModel.user.newMessages()"></span></p>
        <p>new messages, please check report in your dashboard.</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```